# Add HTML after an input element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some HTML after an `input` field using jQuery but it's not working and I don't understand why.

```
<input type="text" value="secret password" maxlength="255" id="ripo" title="Password" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[title='Password']").append('<P>test</P>');
});
```

Comment: append to an input ????? doesn't make any sense

Comment: `jQuery("input[title='Password']").val('<P>test</P>');`

Comment: can you append p in input val ^?

Comment: Sorry I expressed myself somewhat sloppy. I want to add some HTML after an INPUT field, question adjusted.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you at least skim read the methods that jQuery has: http://api.jquery.com. Most of them are self explanatory and give you a good  idea of what can be done with the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.after()` method.

`append` method insert content **to the end of** each element in the set of matched elements.

`after` method insert content **after** each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[title='Password']").after('<p>test</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="secret password" maxlength="255" id="ripo" title="Password" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true">
```

Also, you can use `insertAfter` method in the following way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('<p>test</p>').insertAfter($("input[title='Password']"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="secret password" maxlength="255" id="ripo" title="Password" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true">
```

Comment: The 2nd method will append content to the end of `.parent()` not necessarily after the input. It'll do what OP wanted if the input is the last element in its parent. So `.after()` is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

`append()` is used to add content within an element, however form inputs do not contain any content. Normally you'd use `val()` to set their values.

However to achieve what you require use the `after()` method instead to insert content in to the DOM after the selected element:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ripo").after('<P>test</P>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="secret password" maxlength="255" id="ripo" title="Password" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append HTML to an input. But you can do this (if you wanted to actually set the value):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[title='Password']").val('test');
});
```

Although this does not answer the edited question, other answers address appending an element after the input.

Comment: Just FYI OP updated the question to be more clear about what he's trying to do. `val()` isn't the solution here.

Comment: have updated my answer and left it in case someone else needs this solution to the question.